# CORS issue with Socket.IO and Node.JS on Apache

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, sockets

I've been reading all questions related to this problem. It must be one of the most common issues people face when using Socket.IO and there seems to be many solutions to this problem out there. But none worked for me. Socket.IO and NodeJS work perfectly locally. When I put the code on a VPS, I can't successfully access the socket.io server code because it returns me this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://{THE_SERVER_IP}/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LpxHZS6. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Here is what I tried so far:

1) Using CORS module

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

//Socket.IO code(connection, emit, etc)

io.listen(8080);

console.log('Server running at http://{THE_SERVER_IP}:8080/');
```

2) Setting headers on io variable

```
io.set( 'origins', '*' );
```

NodeJS (without Socket.IO module) works, I was able to render a simple HTML and print a "Hello World" message.

This is the client side code:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-sdmLD9jD1PIzq3KOQPNSGZYxjv76rds79Mnyk5JNp1M=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var socket = io('http://{THE_SERVER_IP}:80/node');

            socket.on('text', function(data) {

                $('h1').html(data);

            });

        });

    </script>
```

If it's necessary, this is how Apache redirects requests to NodeJS server:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@{THE_SERVER_DOMAIN}
    ServerName {THE_SERVER_DOMAIN}
    ServerAlias {THE_SERVER_DOMAIN}
    DocumentRoot /var/www/node/

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia Full
   <Proxy *>
      Require all granted
   </Proxy>

   <Location /node>
      ProxyPass http://{THE_SERVER_DOMAIN}:8080
      ProxyPassReverse http://{THE_SERVER_DOMAIN}:8080
   </Location>

   <Directory "/var/www/node">
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems like your socket.io server listens at 8080 and you are trying to access it at 80, is that alright?

Comment: Well, I thought about that, but there should be no problem with that, since the proxy is redirecting to NodeJS at port 8080. And the NodeJS without Socket.IO was also listening at 8080 and it was working normally.

Comment: But I will try some other port combinations, switching to 80, etc.